# describing all possible topologies on a set

Tags: general-topology

Assuming the following:
let $X$ be a set with two elements, $X$ = {$a,b$}.

what are all the possible topologies on $X$ ?

The answer I've come up with is:
$$\tau_{T}=\{ \emptyset, X\} $$
$$ \tau_{a}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},X\} $$
$$\tau_{b}=\{\emptyset,\{b\},X \} $$
$$ \tau_{D}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},X\}$$

My question is, are these correct? and are there any more?

thanks in advance

Comment: you listed one twice (the first and fourth one are identical) and you are missing one.

Comment: There is a typo in the discrete topology. And I believe that is all.

Comment: So am I missing one or not?

Comment: You're not missing one. You do need to rewrite $\tau_D$ though.

Comment: once you correct the typo in the fourth one (assuming you meant to give the discrete topology, but ended up giving the indiscrete one again), then you'll have them all.

Comment: Yes, your last one is just $\{\varnothing, X\}$ again since $\{a,b\} = X$.

Comment: just to clarify, you should get 4 topologies. But currently you only listed 3.

Comment: You are "missing" the discrete topology; the one you have above is the same as the trivial topology since $X = \{a,b\}.

Comment: Instead of the last one you should write: $$ \tau_{D}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},X\}$$

The argument is given by others above.

Comment: I've just noticed what you ment. Edited and corrected. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is complete because $X$ has only four subsets $\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},X$ after all, the subsets $\emptyset$ and $X$ must occur in each topology, and that leaves only two yes/no choices (and hence four possibilites) as to whether or not $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are open. You listed these four combinatorical possibilities - and they all are indeed topologies!